# Sitecore XConnect XdbCollectionUnavailableException - Forbidden

Tags: xdb, xconnect, data-exchange-framework

I have installed xConnect for sitecore 9.0.2 using SIF 1.2.1 and configured it according to the documentation. I have also installed the xDB Data Migration Tools and when running the Troubleshooter for ***/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/AQR Data Migration Tenant/Endpoints/Providers/xConnect/xConnect Client Endpoint***, I get the following error:

> Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
>   Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden Source:
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1
>   taskFactory)    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1
>   taskFactory)    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode
>   configNode)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String
>   clientConfigPath)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.AsyncPoolScheduler`2..ctor(IAsyncProcessingPool`1
>   pool, IXdbContextFactory xdbContextFactory, ExpandOptions options,
>   Int16 maxBatchSize)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregationAgent.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Agent.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.d__26.MoveNext()

I have also tried the following:

- running Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$*.Issuer -ne $*.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
- Removed the certificates DO_NOT_TRUST_* from Current User/Personal

but the issue still persists.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for your certificate? This is a very helpful post when debugging xConnect certificate issues: https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/10/All-about-xConnect-Security/

Comment: Yes, I have checked this post as well. I have been solving the "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." issue then ran into this one.

Comment: Basically I am facing the same issues described in this post https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10418/the-http-response-was-not-successful-forbidden