# XdbCollectionUnavailableException : The Http response was not successful Forbidden only for English and Portuguese Brazil Language

Tags: sitecore-client, solr, xdb, xconnect, indexing

We are using Sitecore 9.3 in our application and we have updated our certificate as our certificate is going to expire on Aug 31, 2023.
We have updated the thumbprint in all the Sitecore and XConnect instances.
But we are getting the issue "`XConnect XdbCollectionUnavailableException : The Http response was not successful Forbidden`" only for the English and Portuguese Brazil language other websites like French and Chinese is working fine.

Please find the below error in details:

```
The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.
Exception Details: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden

Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:
[XdbCollectionUnavailableException: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden]
   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory) +521
   Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory) +20
   Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode) +93
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +256
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
```

Could you please suggest what could be the possibilities for this issue?

Comment: Give it a try and see if works. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10418/the-http-response-was-not-successful-forbidden

Comment: Are all sites running in same issue instance? Or separate? If separate have you allowed access to private key for each app pool via MMC?